# Regex to remove numbers but keep numbers that are combined with a hyphen

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a regex pattern that will remove everything from my text except letters, hyphen `(-)`, slash `(/)` (e.g., `'[^a-zA-Z-/]'`) and numbers in combination with a hyphen (`'5-'`, `'-123'`). Single numbers or numbers in combination with other characters should be removed, so `'9-SomeWord'`, `'SomeWord-34'` must be kept, but `'456ml'`, `'23'` or `'56%'` should be removed.

What should be the regex pattern?

Comment: So, remove all numbers that aren't either preceded or followed by a hyphen? And for `456ml` the `456` should be removed leaving `ml`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: and `56%` should return nothing because the numbers and the `%` should all be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
r'[^\w/-]+|_|(?<![\d-])\d+(?!\d*-)'
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JBTeRk/2) for testing and further details.